# ECS Application sourcebundle validation error: We expected a VALUE token but got: START_ARRAY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm making an multi-container docker build on Elastic Beanstalk and whenever I run `eb deploy`

I get the error `ECS Application sourcebundle validation error: We expected a VALUE token but got: START_ARRAY`

I think it might be something wrong with my Dockerrun.aws.json, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Here's my dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "ELASTICSEARCH_URL",
                "value": "elasticsearch:9200"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "image": "902260087874.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/the-medical-agora",
        "memory": 128,
        "links": [
            "db",
            "elasticsearch"
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "containerPath": "/usr/src/app",
                "sourceVolume": "."
            }
        ],
        "name": "app",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 3000,
                "hostPort": 80
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "memory": 128,
        "essential": true,
        "image": "postgres:10.3-alpine",
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "sourceVolume": "Db"
            }
        ],
        "name": "db",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 5432,
                "hostPort": 5432
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "memory": 128,
        "essential": true,
        "image": "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.4",
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "containerPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data",
                "sourceVolume": "Esdata1"
            }
        ],
        "name": "elasticsearch"
    }
],
"volumes": [
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "esdata1"
        },
        "name": "Esdata1"
    },
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "db"
        },
        "name": "Db"
    },
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "."
        },
        "name": "_"
    }
]
}
```

Which is weird because when I ran this dockerrun.aws.json [JSON schema linter](https://gist.github.com/sordina/6094aca9bde8acc15158) on it, it seemed to do fine.

The project also works when I run it with `eb local run`.  It seems to only break when I'm deploying it to Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys after reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) of `eb deploy` I discovered the problem.

Although I fixed the Dockerrun.aws.json file, it doesn't reflect on `eb deploy` until I make a new `git commit`.

So I just ran `git add .` and `git commit` and then ran `git push` for good measure.

After that when I ran `eb deploy` it used my new Dockerrun.aws.json and my problems were resolved.